# TypeScript Type alias circularly references itself

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 3.6.3 I get error: `Type alias 'JSONValue' circularly references itself.`

[See code online here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.6.3&ssl=4&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSBlA8gOQApQCWAtoTIQG6oC8cAzjEQHYDmcAPnEwK7EBGwKBzh8IEADbAAhk2E9x4gFChIsBMlSZcWPgCtgAY3i0A3nADaxYP0EAueo0KsAuva04AalPHdUAX2VwaHgkFHRsT29fOFp3AhIySlROdx19I2F3AEEoKClEQNUQjXDcHLzEGNLIn2BzZyA)

I would like to know how to remove this circularly references in this particular version of TS (as same code in more recent version works as expected).

```
export type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
export type JSONObject = { [member: string]: JSONValue }
export type JSONValue = JSONPrimitive | JSONObject | JSONArray
export type JSONArray = JSONValue[]
```

Comment: This is nearly the exact use case mentioned in the [release notes for TypeScript 3.7 detailing added support for more recursive type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#more-recursive-type-aliases).  The answer is in there, including how you have to do it with older versions (intervening `interface` definitions instead of `type` aliases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem using this code, this works on Typescript 3.6.3

[Live version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.6.3&ssl=4&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSBlA8gOQApQCWAtoTIQG6oC8cAzjEQHYDmcAPnEwK7EBGwKBzh8IEADbAAhk2E9x4gNwAoUJFgJkqTLgBqU8dxrps%20IqXJVhOnFj4ArYAGN4nGwEEoUKYhVro8EgoJrh2ji5wtADecADaxMD8ggBc9IyErAC6qTb6hqgAvn7gAXAZMIIAZlJO2qae3ohwoBVMACZ0cA0%20ADy5BkYAfHBRBUA)

```
export type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
export type JSONValue = JSONPrimitive | JSONObject | JSONArray
export type JSONObject = { [member: string]: JSONValue }
export interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> {}
```